# Override fvisibility in Fortran routine

Tags: fortran, visibility, elf, intel-fortran

In a shared object, I can make my Fortran routines unavailable from outside using `-fvisibility=hidden`.

In C/C++ you can override this setting in your routines by `void __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) x () {...}` as described here: http://portal.nacad.ufrj.br/online/intel/compiler_c/common/core/GUID-091C387B-E637-4115-BFC9-1874DD56F50E.htm

Is there a similar way to override the setting in Intel Fortran, such that I can decide which modules or routines in the shared object that can be called from the outside

Comment: Or do you want something similar to the `DLLEXPORT` attribute in Intel Fortran for Windows? That means control which symbols are exported into a shared library?

Comment: Yes something like DLLEXPORT on windows.

Comment: I do not think it is possible, the [relevant attributes](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/a-to-b/attributes.html) are Windows and MacOS only. But you can also ask at the Intel forum directly. This is certainly a compiler-specific issue, the Fortran standard does not touch this.